# How to make cookie-setting javascript cooperate with django.contrib.auth?

Tags: django, cookies, mathjax

Hi I'm trying to make mathjax work in askbot Q&A forum. Got some decent results, but here is a strange issue:

once I add some setting (a feature in mathjax that uses cookies) via right-clicking - django automatically logs me out.

Is there a way to make django authentication not over-react to cookies set via javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: well I found that MathJax sets a cookie named `mjx:menu` but python cookie module does not accept `:` in the cookie name. Changing name to `mjx-menu` fixes the issue, but I have to patch mathjax to make that work, unfortunately. I wonder if there is a work-around in python?

Comment: It depends on how often you update to the latest MathJax -- if it's once a week this could get old fast, if it's once a year then make a note in your WhatINeedToDoWhenIUpdateMathJax.txt file and get on with your life. If ':' is legal in a cookie (I don't know one way or the other), then you might submit a patch to python.org.

Comment: Could you tell me how to enable the mathjax on askbot Q&A?

Comment: Hi, here is some info http://askbot.org/doc/mathjax.html